# Cross-user registry values

Tags: windows, security, registry

I'd come to this conclusion through experience and various things I've read on this internet, but in stating it to a co-worker, it seems illogical.  Can you verify the following statement is true, or provide a counter to it?

**On Vista/Win7, two standard (non-elevated users) cannot read/write the same location in the registry.**

Comment: Why would you expect them to be able to?  Ideally, non-admin users are supposed to be completely isolated from one another, although Windows doesn't follow this principle entirely consistently.

Comment: My particular use case involves machine-specific information retrieved from a web-service, which user A or user B might retrieve, or reset.  I realize the filesystem is generally equivalent in terms of users duplicating or deleting, but the registry is a less common place for users to go deleting willy-nilly.

Comment: One question you need to consider is whether user A's ability to put malicious information in the relevant registry key poses a potential threat to user B.  If it does, then one alternative solution may be to install a service which can modify the key on the user's behalf.  This depends on the context, of course, and may not be an issue in your scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On Vista/Win7, two standard (non-elevated users) cannot read/write the same location in the registry.

This is a false statment

> On Vista/Win7, two standard (non-elevated users) cannot **write** the same location in the registry **in the default configuration**.

But this is true. By default, users only have write access to their own hive (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) and read access to the machine hive (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`).

If you want to configure a location where any user can read *and write*, you can certainly do  by configuring a key's ACL, as @Dark Falcon said. A good place for this is somewhere inside your application's key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, and at install time (when your installer has elevated privileges to do so).

Comment: I believe my primary mistake was that I'd assumed that if I couldn't write to a certain location, I also wouldn't be able to write to lower levels.

Answer (score 2):

That would be incorrect. A registry key can have an ACL specified which allows any user, elevated or not, to write to it. By default, I am not aware of any keys which have this configured, but it certainly is possible.